# How to manually set the start and end time to the AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, http-live-streaming, tvos

Hi usually in tvOS when we play any video with HLS playlist the player won't show the start time of the video. If it is a live streaming it doesn't show both start and end time. is there any way we can manually set these times?

The following image i attached is HLS live streaming. and it is just showing the current time. So if i want to add the start time and the end time is there any way to do that. if it is not please let me know. Thanks for your response.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl4ki.png)

Answer (score 1):

Alright for those who are still looking for the answer,  [watch this Apple Developer Talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/209/)
. All you need to do is to create AVMetaDataItem with `AVKitMetadataIdentifierExactStartDate` with the desired start time.
`AVKitMetadataIdentifierExactEndDate` with the desired end time.

if you are not sure about the exact times then `AVKitMetadataIdentifierApproximateStartDate` and `AVKitMetadataIdentifierApproximateEndDate` should be used.
Hope this helps for someone.